# IDE shows condition always false

Tags: ide

I have this code.

```
enum EnumA {

   VALUE_X(EnumA.EnumB.VALUE_J),
   VALUE_Y(EnumA.EnumB.VALUE_J);

   EnumB propertyC;

   enum EnumB {
      VALUE_J;

      int propertyX;

   }

   EnumA(EnumB c) {
      this.propertyC = c;
   }
}

public class {

   main(...) {
      EnumA.VALUE_X.propertyC.propertyX = 1;
      EnumA.VALUE_Y.propertyC.propertyX = 2;

      if(EnumA.VALUE_X.propertyC.propertyX == EnumA.VALUE_Y.propertyC.propertyX) {
         (Any statement)
      }
   }
}
```

So the problem is that my IDE shows that the condition is always false. But when I run the project the statement get executed (condition is true) why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since enum values are static VALUE_X and VALUE_Y are using the same instance of VALUE_J and have in turn the same value for propertyX.

You are setting it to 1 and right afterwards to 2.

You can check this by logging/printing out the information of both before, between and after the assignments. It should be 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

The reason for your IDE to state it's always false most likely is, that a simple check of the variables shows, they are different.